# Retrieve a list of dates intervals from a first interval and removing stop intervals

Tags: java, algorithm, date

Sorry for the title, the example will be more explicit :p.

I need your help for an algo.

I want to get a `List<Entry<Date, Date>>` with a method like this :

```
List<Entry<Date, Date>> getNonStopDates(Date firstDate, Date lastDate, List<Entry<Date, Date>> listIntervalsStopDates);
```

For example, when I call `getNonStopDates` (if you have a better name I'm interested) with this parameters :

> ```
> firstDate = 01/01/2014
> lastDate = 31/12/2014
> listIntervalsStopDates (the list is always ordered by desc, and there is no overlap):
>  1: 01/02/2014 -> 28/02/2014
>  2: 01/11/2014 -> 30/11/2014
> ```

The result would be :

> ```
> 1: 01/01/2014 -> 31/01/2014
> 2: 01/03/2014 -> 31/10/2014
> 3: 01/12/2014 -> 31/12/2014
> ```

The idea I had would be to browse `listIntervalsStopDates`, consider the number of days difference between the order dates, but I don't know how to implement it (without using Joda Time or something else)...

Here is my first try :

```
public List<Entry<Date, Date>> getNonStopDates(Date firstDate, Date lastDate, List<Entry<Date, Date>> listIntervalsStopDateso) {

    List<Entry<Date, Date>> intervals = new ArrayList<Entry<Date, Date>>();

    intervals.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Date, Date>(firstDate,lastDate));

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(firstDate);

    for (Entry<Date, Date> interval : listIntervalsStopDateso) {

        int daysBetween = (int) ((firstDate.getTime() - interval.getKey().getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }

    return intervals ;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: If you can afford to use an external library, go with Guava and its [`Range`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) and related classes (they include `RangeSet`)

Comment: Can you use the Java 8 time API?

Comment: @cy3er I'm using Java 6 :(

Comment: @almasshaikh Add in first post ;)

Comment: I would indeed use Joda Time. IMHO There's so many date calculations to be done here that it would be well worth while, instead of implementing the low-level date logic yourself on top of the 'broken' java.util.Date or Calendar methods.

Your code would also benefit from moving the date calculations to their own methods.